# Storing an object into a SQL database in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, object-oriented-database

Simply trying to find the correct syntax/method to enter create SQL objects and store them inside an oracle database. (school project so it's got to be possible)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Person AS OBJECT 
(id NUMBER,
 fname VARCHAR(255), 
 lname VARCHAR(255)) NOT FINAL 

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE customer UNDER Person (

  num_purchases NUMBER,
  email VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE Customers (
 id NUMBER,
 cust customer
);

INSERT INTO Customers(id, cust)
VALUES (1, customer(1, "John", "Doe", 44, "doezer@gmail.com"));
```

Returns the error 
**ORA-00984: column not allowed here**

I can't seem to find any way to declare a specific order for putting the values inside of the customer object other than the order that they were declared in. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are inserting `columns` not literal values. replace your `double quotes` to `single quotes`.

```
INSERT INTO Customers(id, cust)
VALUES (1, customer(1, 'John', 'Doe', 44, 'doezer@gmail.com'));

SELECT ID, TREAT(cust AS Person).id, TREAT(cust AS Person).fname FROM Customers;
```

See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=824e7f17df8fe656943fe1d8184fda46)